# Sql query need code

Tags: sql

I want to show the number of employees, the maximum wage, the minimum wage and the average wage ordered by department.

The image of the database:

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Dear friend, why you want spoon feeding. Search the internet, you can easily learn and implement it. And I am sure, you can do it. And remember, its the best if you learn this way.

Comment: We aren't here to solve your program for you. Try something. If you have an error then we'll definately help

Comment: I'm just starting so I've written nothing at the moment...

Comment: @user1915345 Then you need to write *something*, and come back if it does not work. Chances are, you would come back with a different, more advanced, question.

Comment: What you are looking for is most likely described in one of Microsoft's tutorials with their 'Employee' database examples. Going further, you can probably get the same information from Oracle examples.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice i'll try more for the rest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be somewhere close to what you need...

```
select E.Department_ID, count(*), max(E.Employee_Salary), avg(E.Employee_Salary), min(E.Employee_Salary)
    from employee E
    inner join department D on E.Department_ID = D.Department_ID
    group by E.Department_ID
```

Comment: I was wondering - do you mind doing my job for me too while I pursue other interests? (If you don't mind I will keep my pay though)

Comment: Well, if you have a tiny little task you need help with, sure why not? ;)

Comment: More often than not I have large and complex tasks, but I would have never been able to do them if others did all the small tasks for me while I was learning...

Comment: @user1915345 set this answer as correct if you feel it is. Though for the future I would suggest you try something before posting

Comment: It helped me a lot.. just need some fixes... thanx

Answer (score 1):

To get number of employees, look up [SQL Count()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).

To get max / min look up [SQL Max()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) and [SQL Min](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp).

To get averages look at [SQL Avg](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp).

But you know, you could have just found those links yourself in the roughly ten seconds it took me to find them using google, rather than coming on here and expecting someone to to just hand you written code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my query , I Dont have SQL right now to test sorry

```
Select Employee_Id,(Employee_lastName+''+Employee_FirstName) as EmployeeName 
       ,Max(Employee_Salary) as maxWage,Min(Employee_salary) as MinWage , 
        Avg(Employee_Salary)

from   Employee E
       Inner Join Department D on D.Department_Id = E.department_Id

Group By Department_ID
```

Comment: he said group by department -1

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregate functions

http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aaaggregate1.htm

This should help you learn them.

example

1. count to select number of rows
2. max and min for maximum and minimum

Use these in the `SELECT` part of the query

You have to use a group by with these in your case this would be `Department_ID`

Learn the theory and you'll get your answer easily