# Retrieve info sql query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  *
FROM    EMPLOYEE a
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE b
            ON a.Employee_ID <> b.Employee_ID
WHERE   a.employee_salary < b.employee_salary and a.Department_ID='30'
```

Hello I want to retrieve all the info of the employees that earn more money than the employees of department 30

[image of database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqoatxyglgllapr/Untitled.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Together with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13949635/1169798) it seems you want us to write all your code.

Comment: I wrote the code above but i had some problem... i don't need all the code written by others i just need some tips so as to fully understand how sql works for my university. When i have a code in front of me i can edit it and understand it better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  * FROM    EMPLOYEE 
where (Department_ID<>'30')
and 
 (
 employee_salary > 
  (select max(employee_salary) from EMPLOYEE  where  Department_ID='30')
 )
```

Or use SUM istead of MAX if you need employee that  earn more that ALL department 30.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem will help us:

- **First**: You need to know how many money earn deparment 30 employees.
- **Second**: Take employees that earn mora than this money.

The easy way is a query with subquery. The main query retrieve employees than earn more than `X`, the subquery returns `X`.

**Subquery**
How many money earn deparment 30 employees?

```
Select employee_salary from employee where Department_ID='30'
```

**Main query** with subquery:
Employees that earn mora than this money:

```
Select * from employee 
where employee_salary > ANY (
   Select employee_salary from employee where Department_ID='30'
)
```

Notice than you can use `ANY` or `ALL` in subquery operator:

- `ALL` means that you are looking for employees than earn more than `ALL` of dpt 30 employees.
- `ANY` means that you are looking for employees than earn more than `ANY` of dpt 30 employees.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * fROM EMPLOYEE a where a.Department_ID!='30' 
and (a.employee_salary > (select max(b.employee_salary) 
from EMPLOYEE b where b.Department_ID='30'))
```